# Every android phone can use the function one time only depend on android phone id

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to do the function of application detect by android phone? I mean for example, there are many button selection and when i choose one of the button, the button will become red mean i select it and when i uninstall the application and install again, when i open , the button still red mean i cannot choose it again. What i do now is i can select the button and when open again the button i selected still red but when I uninstall or clear the application data, it can choose again. I am using android studio Is this possible to do, If can, please kindly show me the code for android phone id part, thanks....

Answer (score 0):

You can use `server` for that.
**For example, when a button is selected, pass it to server with device id.**

when he opens app either next time or after **re-installing**, check for the `device id` in the `server` and if **exists load the selected button**.

Apart from that you can also **store selected value in other location in mobile and read from there**.

```
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/dir");
dir.mkdirs();
File file = new File(dir, "filename");

FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

And you can write your `deviceId` and `value` in that file.
and later read from it.

Comment: sorry to ask this file is open new java class? or put in the button page activity?